# Magento increase bad performance for applying catalog rules

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, scalability

I am experiencing problems with my magento store.

We currently have +- 700 catalog rules setup for all our customers. 
On a catalog with 2800 products (configurable and simple) and 80 attributes.

Magento version: 1.7.0.2
Compilation: off
Category/product: flattened
Cache: all enabled
Indexes: all enabled

Applying the 700 discount rules via the magento GUI takes forever (>30 min), without getting any feedback. Afterwards no rule gets applied. 
I have tried a shell script found here: http://browse.feedreader.com/c/Drew_Gillson/232210211.
This way I get a lot of feedback when the rules get applied, and about the time it takes to apply rules to a product. 
What I see is that it takes approximately 2 seconds per product to apply all the rules. 
This means that applying all the rules will take 2s * 2800 = 4200s / 60 / 60 = 1:10 hours
This is of course an unacceptable performance issue. As the CPU and RAM usage goes to the roof.
Server which this is hosted on is a VPS with 4GB of RAM (3.5GB free) and 4 dedicated CPU cores. (xeon 2.4GHZ)

When I decrease the number of catalog rules to +- 25, the performance is acceptable (couple of minutes). But for our case we would like to make use of a lot of catalog rules, due to different pricing agreements for different customers.

Is this possible with Magento Catalog Rules? 
Or is there another way to efficiently generate 'catalogrule_product_price' rows in the database, based on the catalog rules.

Thanks,

Wouter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest 2 general approaches:

1) Consider dropping the price index and calculate prices on the fly. This is obviously slower, but it may turn out okay if you use caching properly.

The best way to do this, is create a custom product type and implement your own price logic by extending Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price. Creating a custom product type won't break Magento's core functionality.

You will also need to do something with Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::getFinalPrice(), because in the category view, prices are taken from the index.

Note: You will run into trouble if you want to sort by price or filter by price. These functions run on the database. You'll need to work around this.

2) Consider implementing a partial rule apply function. The price index table (catalog_product_index_price) depends on products, customer groups, websites and tax settings. When one of these changes, you can trigger to update the required rows.

Both routes are quite complex and development intensive, but I'm afraid there's no other solution.

Comment: It took some time but we've developed a faster way to calculate the price rules together with our supplier. It still takes ages to apply the rules, but recalculating the price index was the main thing to speed up and that's very fast now. Thank you for your insights :)

Comment: @Flashin, can I ask what method you used to speed up applying the rules? I am having the same problem due to the size of the catalog.

Comment: they have developed a way to apply them with a own engine.

Comment: we have sped this even more up with Lesti::FPC which supports customer groups http://gordonlesti.com/lestifpc/ and are looking to further improve performance with HHVM